# Swift data caching - best practice

Tags: ios, swift, caching, core-data

I have simple TableViewController with customers. Every cell has photo, name and phone number. I want to cache this information. So when you will be offline or has slow connection, you will see information from last refresh until data refresh again. Refresh will start every time you enter this screen. I will have more screens, where I will want to cache different informations. I want to ask you about best practice of caching in iOS. 
My idea is to use CoreData with Fetched result controller. Is it good idea or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's limited data you need to cache, you can also consider [NSUserDefaults](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-save-user-settings-using-nsuserdefaults) to read - write and delete.